# Sorting Wordpress posts by date entered (Date Picker) in advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, posts, advanced-custom-fields, postorder

I am working in a child theme and need to the category posts to be sorts by the custom field date rather than the wordpress publish date. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is what I have in my `content-single.php` file:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <h1 class="info"><?php the_field('start_date'); ?> - <?php the_field('end_date'); ?></h1>
    <h1 class="info"><?php the_field('time'); ?></h1>
    <h1 class="info"><?php the_field('venue'); ?></h1>
    <a href="<?php the_field('tickets_link'); ?>"><h1 class="buytix">BUY TICKETS<?php the_field('buy_tickets'); ?></h1></a>
        
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'vantage' ) ); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'vantage' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

I am very new to php and wordpress. I am working in a child theme. What code do I need to add so that the posts order by the custom field date and where exactly do I need to put it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify in your WP_query() :

See for examples : 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: thanks but does the $query go into the functions.php?